# Shrinking partition with GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

[image]

What I am trying to do is to shrink /dev/sda4 in order to move the unallocated 9.73 GiB up, and use them to expand /dev/sda1.

However I cannot shrink it, I keep getting the error "Partitions cannot overlap" :( Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Followed the instructions of jet. Partitions now look like this, and I cannot move /dev/sda4 down for some reason :/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need first to move down (toward beginning) sda5 and sda6 one by one in order to move unallocated space at the end and then shrink it

Comment: doesnt seem to work... am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to expand and resize those partitions within /dev/sda4 to the right to move the space from the end (back) of the partition to the beginning (front).

Comment: Umm isn't it what's shown in Screenshot #1? Sorry I really dont get it ;(

Comment: I was able to dig a little deeper today, don't know how feasible this is, but the simplest approach may be to backup files on /dev/sda4, wipe it out, expand /dev/sda1, and redo your other partitions that were inside /dev/sda4.